# como solucionar Uncaught TypeError: $(...).modal is not a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp

Buenas tardes alguien sabae como solucionar el error de : Uncaught TypeError: $(...).modal is not a function?
ya busque en otras publicaciones y ninguna me ha servido
aclaro que solo me funciona la primera vez y de hecho el boton de cerrar no funciona, por lo que debo dar un clic afuera para que se desaparesca...  pero la segunda vez que le doy clic al boton de editar o eliminar no me funciona y me muestra el error

mi codigo en JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {


$(".btnEditar").on('click', function () {
    
    var aHref = $("#btnEditar1").attr('href')//capturo valor de href para enviarlo al controlador desde esta funcion
    var ruta = "Sitio/EditarRequerimiento" + aHref
    $("#modal-content").load(ruta);
    $('#ventanaModal').modal('toggle');

})

$(".btnEliminar").on('click', function () {

    var aHrefDel = $("#btnEliminar1").attr('href')
    var rutaDel = "Sitio/EliminarRequerimiento" + aHrefDel

    jQuery("#modal-content").load(rutaDel);
    jQuery('#ventanaModal').modal('toggle');

})


})
```

Codigo html

```
<table id="miTabla" class="table table-bordered table-responsive display nowrap " cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>

                <th class="text-md-right">
                    Correlativo
                </th>
                <th class="text-md-right">
                    Nombre
                </th>
                <th class="text-md-right">
                    Descripcion
                </th>
                <th class="text-md-right">
                    Fecha
                </th>
                <th class="text-md-right">
                    Departamento
                </th>
                <th class="text-md-right">
                    Tipo
                </th>
              
                <th>Acciones </th>


            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @if (ViewData["Datos"] != null)
            {
                @foreach (var req in ViewBag.DatosConsulta)// ViewData["Datos"] as List<AppTareasIT.Models.TipoRequerimiento>)
                {
                    <tr role='row'>
                        @*<td> </td>*@
                        <td>
                            @req.CorrelativoRequerimiento
                        </td>
                        <td class="text-md-right">
                            @req.Nombre
                        </td>

                        <td class="text-md-right">
                            @req.Descripcion
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @req.FechaRequerimiento.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @req.NombreDepartamento
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @req.NombreTipoRequerimiento
                        </td>
                     

                        <td>
                           
                           <a id="btnEditar1" href="?idReq=@req.CorrelativoRequerimiento" data-toggle="modal" class="btnEditar btn btn-warning"><i class="material-icons">edit</i><span>Editar</span></a>

                            <a id="btnEliminar1" href="?idReq=@req.CorrelativoRequerimiento" data-toggle="modal" class="btnEliminar btn btn-danger"><i class="material-icons">delete</i><span>Eliminar</span></a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                }
            }

        </tbody>
    </table>
```

el modal en el layout esta asi:

```
<!-- Tooltip Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="ventanaModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalTooltip" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content" id="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle2"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i></h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-body">
               
            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark " data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

y asi llamo a los scripts:

```
<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.4/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<!-- extension responsive -->
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.3/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
@*<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>*@

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/sitio.js"></script>
@await RenderSectionAsync("Scripts", required: false)
```

A que se debe el error?

Comment: ¿Por qué estás importando bootstrap 2 veces?

Comment: hola, si no me habia percatado, ya quite el primero, ahora bien sigo teniendo el mismo problema... :/

Comment: y de hecho el que se necesita es el segundo, porque con el primero no me funciona, no me renderiza la vista en el modal si no que manda directamente a la vista

Comment: ¿Dónde estás llamando a los scripts? Por las dudas: se recomienda llamarlos antes de cerrar el `body`, no en el `head`.

Comment: si en el layout antes del cierre del body